# Is there a way to check if "System Preferences" is locked?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, applescript

I want to check if the **"Security & Privacy"** tab is locked or unlocked without doing any modifications to it.
I found a way to do it with AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        if title of button 1 of window 1 is "Click the lock to make changes." then
            log "LOCKED"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

But I get this error:
**"System Events got an error: Script Editor is not allowed assistive access." number -1719 from window 1 of process "System Preferences"**

I want to be able to execute this code on clients' machines so to add **Script Editor** to **Accessibility** is not an option for me.

My question is is there a way (*objective-c, c++ or appleScript*) to just check if the tab is locked or not?

Comment: Just close **System Preferences** if it's opened and that will lock the _tab_.

Comment: System Preferences unlocks on a pane-by-pane basis; there's no generic 'unlocked' state. You should just assume that the pane you're interested in is locked, and then go ahead and do whatever it is you're trying to do. Typically, the system will alert the end-user and ask for the permissions your app/script needs.

Answer (score 1):

While you could write your own `NSPreferencePane` if needed you can also go the official way making the user aware of whats going on by opening the PrefPane you want. So the user can unlock PrefPane them self.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Firewall"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```

To obtain access to locations outside of your app, you must request appropriate entitlements.

To change preferences programmatically read
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPreferences/CFPreferences.html